# Show progress bar when clicking a cell in recycler adaptor, Kotlin, Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, progress-bar, android-recyclerview

I am trying to show an progress bar when I click a cell in a recycler view to show that it is busy.

I have a fragment that when loaded it shows the progress bar no problem(it is just an animated bar and not linked to progress).

I hide the progress bar and when I click a cell in the recycler adaptor I try to make the progress bar visible but no mater what it gives  an error, I have tried it in the bind as well as calling a function in the fragment from the recycler adaptor when the cell is clicked, the function works but when it gets to show the progress bar as visible it gives the error,

> progressBar cannot be null

here is my code

In the recyclerAdaptor

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    when(holder) {
        is HistoryRecyclerAdaptor.HistHolder -> {
            holder.bind(items.get(position))


            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener { v ->




                val pdfN1 = holder.pdf.replace("BBBuxD3Uy/Payments/", "")
                val pdfN = pdfN1.replace(".pdf", "")


                var pdfI = mStorageRef!!.child(usernameGet).child("Payments").child("$pdfN1")


                val localFile = File.createTempFile("$pdfN-", ".pdf")
                pdfI.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener {
                    //            findViewById<PDFView>(R.id.activityMainPdfView).fromAsset(localFile.path).show()

                    val fragment = HistoryFragment()
                    fragment.openFile(holder.itemView.context, localFile.path)

                }.addOnFailureListener {
                    // Handle any errors
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the fragment

```
fun openFile(context: Context, localPath: String?) { // Create URI
    println("Tony Open file hit")
    progressBar2.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    try {
        val file = File(localPath)
        val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
            context,
            context.applicationContext.packageName.toString() + ".provider", file

        )
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        println("Tony Open file hit 2")

        if (file.toString().contains(".pdf")) { // PDF file
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf")
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
            context.startActivity(intent)
            println("Tony Open file hit 3")
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

and the error

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: progressBar2 must not be null

Comment: In your layout do you have a progress bar set? In your ViewHolder layout specifically

Comment: It looks like you've put a progressbar in each one of you recycler view items:
holder.itemView.progressBar2

And in the fragment you are just trying to hide a progressbar in the fragment.

Comment: @beastlyCoder  I have it in the layout file of the fragment.

Comment: @OlleEkberg I have just spotted that and adjusted it in the code, I did try int in the bind function but then tried in the fragment when the method is called

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer.

I added the command to start and stop progress bar in the activity holding the fragment.

Then in the adaptor called this on the click listener

```
(holder.itemView.context as AccountsMainVC).startLoading()
```